# Fix my LaunchAgents

Tags: macos, homebrew

I suspect because my LaunchAgents on MacBook has been interrupted this is what I get when I run…

```
$ ls -ld ~/Library/LaunchAgents
lrwxr-xr-x  1 infacq  staff  46 Aug 16 11:03 /Users/infacq/Library/LaunchAgents -> /usr/local/opt/mysql/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

When try to install other stuff using `brew` it will simply state missing directory. This is what I get when try to perform other stuff.

```
ERROR  watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null 2016-01-23T07:35:13,560: [cli] Failed to open /Users/infacq/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: No such file or directory

Error: watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null 2016-01-23T07:35:13,560: [cli] Failed to open /Users/infacq/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/infacq/Documents/weekdays/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:198:18)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your title is extremely unclear. Can you be more specific with the problem you are facing?

Comment: @grgarside The other packages are "bitching" since the directory to store other plist files isn't a directory. I would say asking for a specific brew command that fails and the error message would be useful  - but I'm fairly certain my answer will solve the issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops is the sound your Mac is making.

I would make a Time Machine backup just in case (or equivalent).

Then you need to remove the link:

```
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Make that directory again (and optionally restore anything from your backup that is now missing)

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

You can then safely re-enable the mysql launch job:

```
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Comment: Once that is done - perhaps check things with `brew doctor`

Comment: is that safe to perform `rm`? I have remove mysql before this. But not aware it links to the lauchAgents

Comment: In your case, the rm deletes a symbolic link. Your system is broken specifically because what should be a folder is actually pointing to a file. The rm doesn't affect mysql or the plist file - just a pointer to that file that happens to be named LaunchAgents. I'm presuming it links since your `ls -ld ~/Library/LaunchAgents` shows me it's a link. In general the rm isn't desirable, but it's safe since a folder can't be removed with `rm` that lacks other options.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul the answer still fits the edited question :)